# Winusb.h missing when switching to VS12 v110_xp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

After switching from a working C++\CLI project on VS12 (update4) platform toolset v110 to v110_xp my build fail on not finding winusb.h.

I can see that in the working project the file founded by the compiler at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\Winusb.h

I can also see that in the original VS10 project the file was found at:
C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk\Winusb.h

Any idea? Help?

Thanks,

Eyal

Comment: Switching to v110_xp also changes the SDK version you use to v7.1A.  The last SDK version that was still compatible with XP.  It doesn't have winusb.h, it is up to you to provide it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still missing something since my VS2010 worked on XP with the winusb from 7600.16385.1. What is this version? Can I point to it from the VS12 v110_xp somehow?

Comment: That is a WDK version.  You still need it.  Add the directory to your project's Additional Include Directories setting, the way you did it in VS2010.

Comment: OK, I tried that and now it is looking for usb.h, so I copied the WinUsb.h and the WinUsbIO.h to my project and after that there where more typedefs needed so I add them to the WinUsb.h and after all that I have the project running on XP!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copy the WinUsb.h and the WinUsbIO.h from WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk to the project directory and add the missing typedefs needed by the compiler to the WinUsb.h.

I did it by taking the type name and Google it, and copy the definition to the file.

After all that I the project is built and running on XP!!

Comment: I think you also need usb.h, usb100.h, and usb200.h, but my info could be outdated.